# IBM Watson Assistant API: "Resource not found" Error

Tags: python, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I'm trying to use the IBM Watson Assistant API in Python to create a session, but I keep encountering an error that I cannot resolve. Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
from ibm_watson import AssistantV2
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator

authenticator = IAMAuthenticator('')
assistant = AssistantV2(
version='2022-05-22',
authenticator=authenticator
)

assistant.set_service_url('https://api.eu-gb.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com')

response = assistant.create_session(assistant_id='').get_result()

session_id = response\["session_id"\]

print(session_id)
```

I've replaced the actual API key and assistant ID with placeholders in this example, but I am using the correct values in my actual code.

When I run this code, I get the following error:
`ApiException: Error: Resource not found, Code: 404 , X-global-transaction-id: 081b1be5-4126-4b79-92c7-c5b60b1b141b`

I've checked that the API key, assistant ID, and service URL are all correct. I've also ensured that the Watson Assistant instance is set to public. However, I'm still getting a 404 "Resource not found" error when trying to create a session.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: Did you ever manage to get this resolved, @RJ2122 ?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation has different examples if you select on the right. Here is the link for the python `create_session`

https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant-v2?code=python#createsession

Here is the sample code at the time of writing.

import json
from ibm_watson import AssistantV2
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator

```
authenticator = IAMAuthenticator('{apikey}')
assistant = AssistantV2(
    version='2021-06-14',
    authenticator = authenticator
)

assistant.set_service_url('{url}')

response = assistant.create_session(
    assistant_id='{environment_id}'
).get_result()

print(json.dumps(response, indent=2))
```

A 404 error normally means that the URL or ID is incorrect (or both). So I would start by checking them.

From the docs as well regarding `assistant_id`

> For message, session, and log requests, specify the environment ID of the environment where the assistant is deployed.

If you are using Actions the environment_id is stored at environments, click the cog beside the Draft/Live title to get it.

If you are using dialog, then it's the assistant ID that can be gotten by the assistant you created that is linked to your skill.